# Ambiguous call to std::atomic function using clang

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, atomic, volatile

I am attempting to compile my code with clang, I was previously using g++.

I am getting errors compiling the following code:

```
#include <atomic>

typedef void (*my_func) ();
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::atomic<my_func> _func;
  _func();
  return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
a.cpp:23:3: error: call to object of type 'std::atomic<my_func>' is ambiguous
  _func();
  ^~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/atomic:304:7: note: conversion candidate of type 'void (*)()'
      operator __pointer_type() const noexcept
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/atomic:307:7: note: conversion candidate of type 'void (*)()'
      operator __pointer_type() const volatile noexcept
      ^
1 error generated.
```

This is not my code, it's legacy code that I need to mantain. In the real code _func is a class member and has a setter and a getter, and from my understanding he intends to protect it so it is not modified when he intends to call it.

Edit:
I am using clang3.6 (same error on clang3.7) and g++ and std::atomic 4.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is 'how to compile the code on CLang' the answer is simple:

```
#include <atomic>

typedef void (*my_func) (int );
int main()
{
  std::atomic<my_func> _func;
  (*_func)(42);
  return 0;
}
```

There is no `operator()` defined on atomic type, so compiler has to perform a type conversion - and there are two options. Another fix is to make `_func` volatile: `volatile std::atomic<my_func> _func;`, but that is much less readable and obvious.

Comment: I'd like to object to the comment about volatile. If you need synchronization between threads, volatile won't do it.

Comment: @Arvid, volatile will simply make the code compilable under CLang due to proper overload detected. I feel like you are reacting to `volatile` in context of multithreading without actually reading the post.

Comment: Ooops, looks like my message is ambiguos. Will edit for clarity.

Comment: oh, I see. I interpreted the last sentence as an alternative to using std::atomic, I suppose I wasn't giving you the benefit of the doubt there. +1 for the update

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to edit these sources I would recommend you to replace the function call with something like `_func.load()();`. This code does essentially the same thing but allows you to avoid the ambiguous call.

The same issue present in MS's Visual C++ compiler.
I guess it is general problem with atomic interface design.